# Wordpress : How canget category name for post from post type

Tags: wordpress

I've got post_type = foods in my wordpress page, and I need to get the category of each post in this post type.

how can i do that.

this code is to det info of post :-

```
$ps = new wp_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'foods' , 'posts_per_page' => '6'  ) );

                    if($ps->have_posts())
                    {
                    while($ps->have_posts())
                    {
                    $ps->the_post();
?>
<div class="reviews-left1"><a href="<? the_permalink(); ?>"><? the_title(); ?></a></div>
<div class="reviews-left1">Category :    </div>
<? }} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have a custom `post_type` I assume you have also a custom `taxonomy` related to the Food that you call "Category"

Here is a function which will return all terms of a taxonomy for a post:

```
 <?php $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy, $args ); ?>
```

Your code should be:

```
<?php $ps = new wp_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'foods' , 'posts_per_page' => '6'  ) );
if($ps->have_posts())
{
  while($ps->have_posts())
  {
    $ps->the_post();
    $food_cateogries = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'YOUR-TAXONOMY-ID');
?>
<div class="reviews-left1"><a href="<? the_permalink(); ?>"><? the_title(); ?></a></div>
<div class="reviews-left1">Category : <?php echo implode(',', $food_categories); ?></div>
<? }} ?>
```

See more here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms

Comment: i will try but show me this error  `Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed `

Comment: `implode` function works with arrays, so be sure that `$food_categories` has value and YOUR-TAXONOMY-ID is correct.

Comment: from where can i get YOUR-TAXONOMY-ID ??

Comment: i will try this but get my class array  `$food_cateogries = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'foods_categories');
print_r($food_cateogries);`